# get chart values in chart js in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

[image: picture]

As it is a stacked chart i need to get the values in above chart like  april,wellness and count 148 i used the below code:

```
 onClick: function (e) {
                        var activePointLabel = this.getElementsAtEvent(e)[0]._model.label;
                        alert(activePointLabel);
                    }
```

But i get only April but i need all the above , when i click i need to get like april,wellness and 148

my chart full code is :

```
window.allSession = new Chart(ctxSession, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
               labels: dates,
               datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Emotional',
                    data: resEmotional,
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 156, 182)'   ,
                                hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 156, 182)'   ,
                                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                                hoverBorderColor: 'lightgrey'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Mental',
                    data: resMental,
                                backgroundColor:  'rgb(117, 117, 117)'     ,
                                hoverBackgroundColor:  'rgb(117, 117, 117)'     ,
                                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                                hoverBorderColor: 'lightgrey'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Others',
                    data: resOthers,
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(225, 58, 55, 0.7)",
                                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(225, 58, 55, 0.7)",
                                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                                hoverBorderColor: 'lightgrey'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Wellness',
                    data: resWellness,
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(253, 186, 49)' ,
                                hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(253, 186, 49)' ,
                                hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                                hoverBorderColor: 'lightgrey'
                },
                ]
            },
            
            
            options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked:true,
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked:true,
                            barPercentage: 0.4
                        }],events:[]
                    },
                    onClick: function (e) {
                        var activePointLabel = this.getElementsAtEvent(e)[0]._model.label;
                        alert(activePointLabel);
                    }
                }
        });
```

Kindly help me to sort out this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ciao, can you show me `resWellness`?